# Sending multicast udp from multihomed computer

Tags: c, udp, posix, multicast

I need to send a multicast udp from multihomed computer. Found that in case socket is not bound to some specific interface, default interface will be used (whatever it could mean). My question: is it possible to specify something like inaddr_any to send multicast udp from all available interfaces or is it only possible to do that by enumerating all interfaces and manually send from each? Is there a standard for that?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set which network interface IPv4 multicast packets leave from by setting the `IP_MULTICAST_IF` socket option.  The value passed to `setsockopt` should be the address of a `struct in_addr` containing the IP address of the interface in question.

If you want to send a multicast packet on multiple interfaces, you'll need to call `sendto` multiple times, setting the `IP_MULTICAST_IF` option before each one.

Comment: I understand that i can explicitly set the interface. I asked about another thing. The question is: 1) is it possible to send via all interfaces without sending manually via each interface? 2) is there a standard document describing such a behavior?

Comment: @BbIKTOP A packet can only leave from one interface. You'll need to loop through them to send from more than one.

Comment: i cannot use anonymous comment as a reference. Is it stated in any standard document?

Comment: @BbIKTOP I'm not aware of any standard document related to how sockets are supposed to work.  The socket API originated in BSD UNIX and other OS's picked it up with minor differences here and there.

Comment: I asked about standards, i do know how it works in bsd etc.  but thank you for letting me know that you’re not aware though